# Remove password policies from profiles and have only one central password policy?

Tags: security, passwords

In our org, some profiles have their own password policy; these overwrite the general password policy. I would like to return to having only one centralized policy. How can I do that? I cannot find a way to do this via Setup. Could I do this by updating the metadata for profiles directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it via metadata.

Thing your looking for is called ProfilePasswordPolicy

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ProfilePasswordPolicy</name>
</types>
```

[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm)

Comment: For documentation: After deleting the ProfilePasswordPolicy files, they are generated again with the settings from the central password policy. So this works.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem, I tried the Salesforce CLI command

> sfdx force:source:delete -m ProfilePasswordPolicy

but this returned error **No ProfilePasswordPolicy named: * found**

Profile password policy metadata API names are not simple or predictable, e.g. `PT2_profilePasswordPolicy12524392843`, so this 2-steps approach worked for me to remove all profile-specific password policies:

1. sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ProfilePasswordPolicy
2. sfdx force:source:delete -p your/source/path/to/profilePasswordPolicies --noprompt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to remove them from each profile and then set on Organization-wide Password Policy.

Here are steps to change it on profile.

- From Setup, enter Profiles in the Quick Find box, then select Profiles.
  Select a profile.
- Depending on which user interface you’re using, do one of the following.

  - Enhanced profile user interface—Click Password Policies, then click Edit.
  - Original profile user interface—Click Edit, then scroll to the Password Policies section.
- Change the values for the profile.

Here are steps for Org wide settings.

- From Setup, enter Password Policies in the Quick Find box, then select Password Policies.
- Customize the password settings.

Some good read for you:

[Set Password Policies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_password.htm&type=5)

[View and Edit Password Policies in Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_password_policies.htm&type=5)

[Manage Password Expiration with Password Policies and Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000229780&type=1)

Comment: Hi Tushar, I can edit them on the profile (for example changing "User passwords expire in"), but I cannot remove the password policy settings. I cannot set the settings to be empty.